# need to call native function that returns 128bit value with JNA (objc_msgSend)

Tags: java, macos, jna, 128-bit

I'm writting a JNA binding for ObjectiveC and I have a problem:

[NSValue sizeValue] returns an NSSize structure.

Normally you would think to use objc_msgSend_stret but when the structure is small enough it is returned in registers so you must use just objc_msgSend in this case.
NSSize is two floats in 32bit mode, so that's basically a long.  No problem.  I use Function.invokeLong() and then grab the pointer to my structure and write the long to the two float storage space.
But in 64bit mode it's two doubles which is 128bits.  I used GCC --save-temps and sure enough the returned structure is in xmm0 and xmm1.  So objc_msgSend must be used.

JNA doesn't have a Function.invokeLongDouble() or Function.invokeLongLong() (128bit return value)

What do I do???

See this link for more details on objc_msgSend and structures:
http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/10/30/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_stret.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

[NSValue getValue:void*] will work.  It's places the contents into the pointer.